# What's the correct order of negated adjectives?

Tags: word-order, negation, modifiers

Do adjectives with "not" go **before** or **after** the noun they refer to?
For example:

1. A not funny guy
2. A guy not funny

Which of these is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't tend to use adjectives like this:

Either use an adjective with the opposite meaning

> an unfunny guy

> a humourless guy

Or use a clause

> a guy who is not funny

None of these expressions are sentences.  In a sentence you could say

> That guy is not funny.

Answer (score 3):

The negation ("not") goes before **all** of the adjectives, including the **article adjectives (a, the)**. `He is not a funny guy.`

For multiple negated adjectives, add the conjunction "nor": `He is not a funny nor a nice guy.`